# ERROR: cout c++ undeclared

Tags: c++, cout

I'm learning c++, following example trows "`Enter' undeclared (first use this function) ". 
I've been reading some questions in this site and it seems it has to do with not declaring functions. But I can't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//
// Program to convert temperature from Celsius degree
// units into Fahrenheit degree units:
// Fahrenheit = Celsius * (212 - 32)/100 + 32
//
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
// enter the temperature in Celsius
int celsius;
cout << “Enter the temperature in Celsius:”;
cin >> celsius;
// calculate conversion factor for Celsius
// to Fahrenheit
int factor;
factor = 212 - 32;
// use conversion factor to convert Celsius
// into Fahrenheit values
int fahrenheit;
fahrenheit = factor * celsius/100 + 32;
// output the results (followed by a NewLine)
cout << “Fahrenheit value is:”;
cout << fahrenheit << endl;
// wait until user is ready before terminating program
// to allow the user to see the program results
system(“PAUSE”);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you typing this up on Microsoft Word?

Comment: No, In DEV C++ IDE, In fact I didn't type it. I copied the example from C++ For dummies 5th edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
cout << “Enter the temperature in Celsius:”;
```

to

```
cout << "Enter the temperature in Celsius:";
```

`“”` and `""` are different.

Answer (score 3):

Please use a simple text editor or an IDE. Your quotes are not correct.

```
cout << “Enter the temperature in Celsius:”;
```

should be changed to

```
cout << "Enter the temperature in Celsius:";
```

The error is thrown because the quotes are supposed to be like `"` not `”`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm using dev c++ IDE.